# ng-show="false" and input type="number" and min validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

In my cshtml page I am using input type="number" with min validation. I also conditionally show this control. I only want to validation to fire when the control is visible ng-show="true" but it fires in both cases (for ng-show="false") as well. Here is example: [Modified sample Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cNahYe8QpNITkDBe3YE3?p=preview)

My control is the following:

```html
<input type="number" name="maxSale" ng-show="!selections.createDaily"
                           id="maxSale"
                           ng-model="currentmax4sale.maxSale"
                           class="form-control"
                           min="1"
                           required
                           data-sm:number
                           data-sm:number-format data-sm:focus
                           data-accuracy="0" />
                    <div class="field-validation-error">

                        <span ng-show="form.editMax4saleGeneralForm.maxSale.$error.required && form.editMax4saleGeneralForm.maxSale.$dirty">@String.Format(Messages.isRequired, Labels.limit)</span>

                        <span ng-show="(form.editMax4saleGeneralForm.maxSale.$error.min ) && form.editMax4saleGeneralForm.maxSale.$dirty">
                            @String.Format(Messages.mustBeGreaterThanOrEqualTo, Labels.limit, "1")
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

What should I do to have only conditional validation when my control is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd really suggest you to use `ng-if`, basically the markup is still there but with `ng-if` it will remove it from the DOM so it isn't even rendered hence solves your problem. You can also change the logic in which you are testing but I think you just don't want the item in the markup at all.

Comment: ng-if sounds like a better solution. I'll try it instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using {{}} conditional value, e.g.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cNahYe8QpNITkDBe3YE3?p=preview

```html
min="{{selections.createDaily?'0': '1'}}"
```